# ui-grid enableSelectAll and paginationPageSize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have a grid and I would like giving a pagination size of 10, I want to select all options to restrict row selection to only 10, but given this configuration, it selects entire data set across all pages.

```
$scope.gridEvents = {
  enableSorting :           true,
  enableSelectAll:          true,
  enableColumnResize:       true,
  enablePaginationControls: false,
  rowHeight:                27,
  enableScrollbars :        true,
  paginationPageSize :      10
}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as shown below.

Working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3XSHuR3TMn3NZTxqeUnQ?p=preview)

***JS***

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 30],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    useExternalPagination: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    totalItems: 100,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'gender' },
      { name: 'company' }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged( $scope, function( currentPage, pageSize){
        $scope.getPage(currentPage, pageSize);

       });
    }
  };

 $scope.getPage = function(pageNumber, pageSize){
    var startingRow = pageSize * ( pageNumber - 1);   // page number starts at 1, not zero
    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function (data) {
      var newData = [];
      for( var i = startingRow; i < startingRow + $scope.gridOptions.paginationPageSize; i++ ) {
        newData.push( data[i] );
      }
      $scope.gridOptions.data = newData;
    });
  };

  $scope.getPage(1, 10);
```

**Html**

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
```